# Как быстро google проиндексирует 8000 поддоменов?

Tags: веб-программирование, поиск, seo, индексация

у меня есть вебсайт с такой структурой:

```
/ -- главная страница
/regions/ -- все регионы (вверху показывается 20 популярных городов, ~80 регионов ниже)
/regions/1 -- переходим на регион со списком городов (около ~40 шт в каждом регионе)
```

сайт ссылается на поддомен %название-города%.mywebsite.com

Как быстро мне проиндексировать их, можно ли ускорить индексацию?